# Seeking a detailed and comprehensive book on plane geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I'm really tired of going through tons of wikipedia pages. Wikipedia is a good thing, but at one point one who wants to go deeper needs an ordered, comprehensive and formal treatment. Me at least.

Therefore, I would like some recommendations for detailed and comprehensive books on plane geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You will find Coxeter's Introduction to Geometry covers plane geometry formally from a range of perspectives. It does more than two dimensions, but plane geometry is thoroughly covered throughout. It covers non-euclidean and inversive geometry, and is (in my view) rightly regarded as a classic.

Heath's translation and commentary on Euclid should not be forgotten.

Comment: Second that about Coxeter. There is an amazing amount of stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read Spanish there is a series of books by Mario O. Gonzalez. I think it is a very good work.

Benjamin Peirce, An elementary Treatise on Plane and Solid Geometry

Comment: I should I presume; my native language is italian so I could give a try. Thank you!

Comment: Though it looks like I can't find any..any specific title you could  remember?

Comment: Thank you all very much misters.